# I want to receive physical keyboard key press in Xamarim forms for iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to receive physical keyboard key press in Xamarim forms for iOS. 
Following code works well taken from this link :

[Is it possible to hook into Hardware keyboard events at an Application level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220710/is-it-possible-to-hook-into-hardware-keyboard-events-at-an-application-level/47246214)

But it works only for numeric keys. It does not work for alphabets like "A". Added as show below.

UIKeyCommand acceleratorA = UIKeyCommand.Create((NSString)"A", 0, selector);
        AddKeyCommand(acceleratorA);

Any reason why not working for alphabets. Do I have to set keyboard type. If yes how?

Code starts here :

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MobileProject.MainPage), typeof (com.YourCompany.iOS.KeyboardHookRenderer))]
namespace com.YourCompany.iOS
{
public class KeyboardHookRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    private string _RecvValue = string.Empty;

    public override bool CanBecomeFirstResponder
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        string key = string.Empty;
        var selector = new ObjCRuntime.Selector("KeyRecv:");
        UIKeyCommand accelerator1 = UIKeyCommand.Create((NSString)"1", 0, selector);
        AddKeyCommand(accelerator1);
        UIKeyCommand accelerator2 = UIKeyCommand.Create((NSString)"2", 0, selector);
        AddKeyCommand(accelerator2);
        UIKeyCommand accelerator3 = UIKeyCommand.Create((NSString)"3", 0, selector);
        AddKeyCommand(accelerator3);

        ... etc as many as you need or use a loop based on key id...
    }

    [Export("KeyRecv:")]
    public void KeyRecv(UIKeyCommand cmd)
    {
        if (cmd == null)
            return;
        var inputValue = cmd.Input;
        if (inputValue == "\n" || inputValue == "\r")
        {
            ((MobileProject.MainPage) Element)?.HandleHardwareKeyboard(_RecvValue);
            _RecvValue = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            _RecvValue += inputValue;
        }
    }
}
}

/// <summary>
/// Handle hardware keys (from KeyboardHookRender.cs in iOS project)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="keys">Keys sent, including trailing Cr or Lf</param>
public void HandleHardwareKeyboard(string keys)
{
    SomeTextbox.Text = keys;
    // Whatever else you need to do to handle it
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it really works well on my side. You need to press `CapsLock` and `A` at the same time to make your code work. Are you missing something or can  you provide a simple demo?

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention one point... my physical keyboard is Keyboard wedge device... i.e. HID scanner from Honeywell handheld device. Now obvious question will be: need to set some settings on HID scanner ... but then with same settings I am able to receive keyboard keys in Text input field which is placed on the same app form.

Comment: Hello rajpat, did you figure out what to do? Could you share your findings? Thanks