# Is it possible to set a low level keyboard hook In Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application for iOS and Android.

I would like to hook into keyboard events at a low level so that when a user presses a key on the keyboard, doen't matter in which application, I can invoke an action in my application and recive the pressed key.

The closest thing I've found yet is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220710/is-it-possible-to-hook-into-hardware-keyboard-events-at-an-application-level) question, but it talks about application-wide hook, not a world-wide hook.

Is it possible to set a low level keyboard hook In Xamarin?

Comment: You would need to review "accessibility services" for Android and the iOS Accessibility APIs (they are spread across OS). Android Accessibility Service has the most access beating the iOS exposed features, but it also requires the user manually enable the app containing the service to be allowed to access all apps/fields (this is how password managers, etc... are able to work)

Comment: @SushiHangover can you add some more information? Maybe an article that talks about it? I coudn't figure out what are accessibility services, and how to use it.

Comment: I think this would violate some security policies and there would be no ready-made API exposed